# Staging S3 files with External Tables directly

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to find a way to directly querying csv, json and avro files without having to stage the files first.

Is there a way to do this?

What I have found so far are:

1. External Tables https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/tables-external-intro.htm
2. Another tool called FiveTran, that lets me correct any automatic
   detection of the files -> table detection

Is there another way to directly read the file to Snowflake without staging the file?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by stage? Are you trying to avoid staging them within Snowflake (e.g. reading them from something like AWS S3) or trying to avoid staging them anywhere (read from a local store, stream from a source system)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query files directly on s3 if you create a Snowflake "stage" object which references that s3 bucket/location.

Details can be found here:

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/querying-stage.html#querying-data-in-staged-files

In this situation, you aren't actually "loading" data into Snowflake, you're just creating a "stage" object in the database which turns out to be a "pointer" to the s3 location.

I hope this helps...Rich

Answer (score 1):

All files must be staged in either an internal or external location that is referenced by a stage object.  Using external tables can be done to integrate with Apache Hive Metastores, but still require a stage object. 
 They can be somewhat limiting and slower since the data is not stored in Snowflake.

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/tables-external-hive.html

**What are you trying to avoid by not staging your files?**

Comment: It was a security policy, still working through it.  I will check out this tool.